# ¿como hago una consulta sobre otra consulta MySQL con Node.js?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

tengo creado un `pool`de MySQL

```
module.exports = () => {
return mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'gym'
});
```

}

también tengo hecha una consulta que si me muestra resultados

```
const dbConnection = require("../modelos/config.connection");
const connection = dbConnection();
connection.getConnection(function(error, conn){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    } // consulta que muestra los datos
    connection.query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM inventario LIMIT ? , ? ', [consulta.INICIO, consulta.ARTICULOS_POR_PAGINA], function(error, articulos)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                throw error;
                connection.release();
                res.status(500).send({message: error});
            }else
            {
                connection.query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total', function(error, result)
                {
                    if(error)
                    { throw error; } 
                    else {
                        var total = result[0].total;
                        res.status(200).send({total})
                }

            }
        );
    })
connection.end();
```

mi problema comienza ahora que la consola me marca error de `Pool is closed`.
ademas otro problema que dice que `no se puede volver enviar cabeceras al cliente cuando ya se ha hecho`.
entonces... como puedo hacer esta consulta? ya que de lo que me de la primer consulta quiero obtener el total de filas para poder hacer una paginacion en base a ello.
espero alguien me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Estoy viendo que estás cerrando la conexión al final:

```
connection.end();
```

Yo eliminaría eso. Simplemente hace un release, algo así:

```
const dbConnection = require("../modelos/config.connection");
const connection = dbConnection();
connection.getConnection(function(error, conn){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    } // consulta que muestra los datos
    connection.query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM inventario LIMIT ? , ? ', [consulta.INICIO, consulta.ARTICULOS_POR_PAGINA], function(error, articulos)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                throw error;
                connection.release();
                res.status(500).send({message: error});
            }else
            {
                connection.query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total', function(error, result)
                {
                    if(error)
                    { throw error; } 
                    else {
                        var total = result[0].total;
                        connection.release();
                        res.status(200).send({total})
                }

            }
        );
    })
```